# Why #temptable instead @tempTable causing a timeout error?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure called `myStoredProcedure` in SQL Server 2008 including a code block like this:

```
...
declare @tempTable table
(
   Id int,
   Name varchar(100),
   Category varchar(50),
   Volume int
)

while @startTime<@endTime
begin
   insert into @tempTable
   EXEC R52_Calculations @param1, @param2, @param3

   set @startTime = DATEADD(YEAR,1,@startTime)
end

select * from @tempTable
```

In this way, the stored procedure is working very well. I can connect to a table to this stored procedure in the SSRS 2008 without any warning or error. However, when I change `@tempTable` variable into `#tempTable` like below, I am getting a TimeOut error when I try to connect a table on SSRS 2008 to the updated stored procedure, even though the stored procedure is working very well again in SQL Server.

```
...
create table #tempTable
(
   Id int,
   Name varchar(100),
   Category varchar(50),
   Volume int
)

while @startTime<@endTime
begin
   insert into #tempTable
   EXEC R52_Calculations @param1, @param2, @param3

   set @startTime = DATEADD(YEAR,1,@startTime)
end

select * from #tempTable
```

This is the error:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
>   the operation or the server is not responding. Warning: Null value is
>   eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Some more points:

1. when I remove the "while" loop and do the process only 1 time, there is no error occurring when I use #tempTable.
2. if I use @temptable (variable one), there is no error occurring at all.

Note that both queries are working fine in SQL Server, the errors are occurring when I try to connect a table on SSRS 2008 to the stored procedure
.

I could not find the reason why #temptable is causing an error. Any clue or help I will appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a timeout, so it's coming from somewhere else. Why your run takes longer, for that you most likely need to check what happens -- is the query plan different, is there blocking etc.

Comment: may be the data set, this sp returns is huge and ssrs report has time out value

Comment: @TheGameiswar if so, why do you think using a table of variable works well but #temptable does not?

Comment: if you are able to repro this everytime with #temp table,then do you have an estimate on when this time out occurs,is this immediately after the loop, or half way through the execution

Comment: @TheGameiswar  half way through the execution seems like